# How to make JFrame INVISIBLE with a JPanel that is VISIBLE?

Tags: java, swing

I'm sorry for using caps, my last attempt of asking this question wasn't clear which is fine.
How do I make the JFrame fully invisible, not: '.setUndecorated(true)', but actually invisible and put a JPanel on that JFrame that is visible.
So pretty much, the JPanel will act as a JFrame, but I need the JFrame to be bigger than the JPanel because I'd like to add shadow around the JPanel, which has been figured out already.

Comment: Is JWindow what you are looking for?

Comment: Normally, if a `Container` isn't visible, it's children will not be either

Comment: @ControlAltDel I'll be looking into it! Thank you for the suggestion! I also didn't know about that!

Comment: (1-) Don't repost question. Keep all the information in one place so everybody knows what has already been suggested. An undecorated frame will appear the same as a JWindow. You still haven't defined what "invisible" means to you or why an undecorated frame doesn't do what you want. Also, post an [mre] demonstrating you problem so we can see exactly what your problem is. An image is also helpful when asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the frame background transparent:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setBackground(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f));

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(500, 400);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(new JLabel("Top", SwingConstants.CENTER), BorderLayout.NORTH);
panel.add(new JLabel("Bottom", SwingConstants.CENTER), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
panel.add(new JLabel("Right", SwingConstants.CENTER), BorderLayout.EAST);
panel.add(new JLabel("Left", SwingConstants.CENTER), BorderLayout.WEST);

frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! This actually worked! I tried searching but nothing helped. Wow. Thank you so so much!